# PHP Create Array

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm trying to generate an array that will look like this:

Array ( [123 Smith St, Begora] => L1234 [55 Crumble Road, Mosmana] => L2456 [99 Jones Ave, Gestana] => L3456 )

which will ultimately be used for a select menu on an html form.

I'm retrieving a list of records and propertyID numbers from a database as follows:

```
            foreach($records as $record) {
                    $propertyID = $record->getField('propertyID');
                    $property = $record->getField('propertyAddress');  

                    echo $propertyID.'<br>'; 
                    echo $property.'<br>';              
            }
```

which displays like this when I retrieve 3 records:

L1234
123 Smith St, Begora
L2456
55 Crumble Road, Mosmana
L3456
99 Jones Ave, Gestana

I just can't work out how to convert this into an Array which I can then use later on in my page for generating a select menu.

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to have spaces etc in key names. Especially as you could start getting addresses with apostrophes etc in them

Comment: Hi - not sure what you're referring to here by "spaces in key names"? Can you clarify - thanks.

Comment: In the example you gave above you would have an array with the key name `[123 Smith St, Begora]` it would be much better for this to be the value rather than the key where an array is made up of `array("key"=>"value")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    $propertyID = $record->getField('propertyID');
    $property = $record->getField('propertyAddress');  

    $addresses[$property] = $propertyID;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use $propertyID for the array index, since it's shorter and easier to sort.

Comment: It is also less likely to include non alpha chars

Comment: aynber and Anigel yeah i would too, but I was trying to produce output to match OP's requirements in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$array = array();
foreach($records as $record) {
        $array[$record->getField('propertyAddress')] = $record->getField('propertyID');            
}
```